# Vue.js: toggle class onclick

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to set a class depending on if certain values are true.

My div:

```
<template>
<div class="navbar" v-bind:class=" {'test1': static, 'test2': isActive } ">
</template>
```

and in the script part of my component, I've written this:

```
<script>

export default {
  name: 'my-component',
  data: {
    static: true,
    isActive: true
  }
}

</script>
```

According to my understanding, this should show both the `test1` class, and the `test2` class. What am I misunderstanding -- shouldn't this be working? I want to toggle classes on click of a button, but I can't get this part working.

Comment: In a component, data needs to be a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data needs to be a function in a component.

```
export default {
  name: 'my-component',
  data(){
    return {
      static: true,
      isActive: true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks for the quick answer. This works well for my purposes -- thank you!